# GUI for setfacl or other NTFS equivalents?

Tags: windows, filesystem, permissions, ntfs, file-sharing

I would like to setup a small office network based on ubuntu machines to replace the current based on windows. One of the requirements is to setup a `samba` share for file sharing. The problem is that unix permission system of `user`-`group`-`others` isn't granular enough to offer same functionality as `NTFS` permissions.

I had a look around and found `setfacl` which looks like it could do the job in terms of replacing `NTFS`, however I don't want to have to setup the permissions manually via the CLI.

**Q1: Is there a GUI for `setfacl`?**
**Q2: Are there alternatives to `setfacl` to offer similar functionality as `NTFS` also equiped with a GUI?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes, there is a GUI to setup ACLs, its name is `eiciel`, and you can see some screenshots in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82628/how-to-make-a-directory-with-permanent-permissions-different-from-default/82645#82645);
2. I don't know of any alternatives to ACL.

Comment: Thanks. I've played a bit with `Eicel`, the problem is that you have to manually open files 1 by 1 to set their permissions. They should integrate a file browser with the ability to visualize or set permissions on multiple files/folders at once to be really useful. If you have to manage permissions on a whole network share with `Eicel` you will probably end up jumping off a bridge before you're done with setting the permissions :(

Comment: @user359650: as you can read in that answer, eiciel is integrated with nautilus context menu. Don't know if you can work on multiple files, though.

Comment: `eiciel` is pretty but ridiculously inefficient. Sadly it always goes back to the same thing in Linux, you have to open the terminal and type obscure commands to get anything done.