# User www-data in custom group does not give other user write access

Tags: permissions, chmod

This is somewhat confusing for me so i hope someone can quickly explain the run down once and forall.

I have a User, "`John`", and group created named "`John`". I  make john a "Primary group members" of group John, and user `www-data` a member also of group John.

I create /home/john and `chown john:john`.

files and directories are `chmod 755`, so it makes sense then that `www-data` cannot write, which i want it to.

Do i need to chmod everything to 775, or is there a better way to go about this securely?

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to go:

1. `chmod 775`
   If I understood you correctly, the user `www-data` is part of the group `john`. So in this setting this user can also write to your directories.
2. `chown www-data`
   You can also transfer the ownership of your directories to `www-data`. Now obviously `www-data` can write. However in this setting the user `john` can't write.
3. Use POSIX ACLs
   ACL stands for access control list. Using this mechanism you can give additional users additional rights, i.e. write for `www-data`. See this answer for a description: [How to make a directory with permanent permissions different from default](https://askubuntu.com/q/82628/236)

Answer (score 0):

I think 755 is appropriate permission if you don't want other group members to write to that area and read only, but if you really want groups to write should use 775.